# Calculate Euclidean distance in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, knn, euclidean-distance

I’m trying to build a lookalike in pyspark.
Basically finding a closest customer from control dataset(2M size) for test population(20k size)

I have created vectors for both datasets
Now I want to find euclidien distance for one test customer with every control customer. Then find minimum and get related customer id in front of test customer.

Test dataset:

```
Cust_nbr | features
1234     | [1,2,4,…]
```

Control dataset also looks the same.

I want output to be like this:

Test dataset:

```
Cust_nbr | lookalike cust_nbt
1234     | 2356
```

I tried by converting test customers into a list and then iterated over it. Calculated distance for every control customer they tried to get minimum distance customer id in a list and appended in a list at every iteration. But getting o59951 collectToPython error